# Placeholder in HTML editor text area?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, html-editor

I am trying to make a placeholder appear on the default html editor on a specific post type.
The code looks like this:

```
add_filter('the_editor','add_placeholder_event');
function add_placeholder_event( $html ){
if ( 'event' == $post->post_type )
    $html = preg_replace('/<textarea/', '<textarea placeholder="my place holder text" ', $html);
return $html;
}
```

It does not work, however, if I remove `if ( 'event' == $post->post_type )` from the code it will work (but will apply to every html text editor on Wordpress).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The editor is not a normal textarea. It is TinyMCE, and TinyMCE does not use a textarea. It's a HTML document in an iframe.

Comment: I have disabled the WYSIWYG/TinyMCE editor, and using only the standard html/text editor for this post type. Or what do you mean? It does work for me, I just can't make it only apply to a custom post type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it:

```
function add_placeholder_event( $html ){
$screen = get_current_screen();
$post_type = $screen->post_type;

if( $post_type == 'event' ) {
    $html = preg_replace('/<textarea/', '<textarea placeholder="John Doe" ', $html);
}
return $html;
}
add_filter('the_editor','add_placeholder_event');
```